# GCC 4.9 error on #define with __attribute__

Tags: gcc

I am trying to build ctags with MinGW 4.9, but got errors below:

```
 general.h:60:22: error: expected ')' before '__attribute__'
 # define __unused__  __attribute__((unused))
                      ^
```

I've searched and got something perhaps alike: http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/message/28359739/

But still cannot solve my problem. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: `#define` causes the preprocessor to replace text. No syntax error can occur. Show the code that uses `__unused__`. And try to avoid spaces after `#`.

Comment: I tried removing spaces after `#` and made no difference. BTW, I am using MinGW-w64, and the error message seems to be a syntax error, will that probably be a bug of the compiler?

Comment: When any error with a preprocessor define occurs it might be useful to look at the preprocessor output. The GCC should accept the `-E` to produce it.